# Differing one button from another on a prototype object jquery

Tags: javascript, button

first, the prototype:

```
function Notification (title, message, id) {
    var $title = this.title = title;
    var $message = this.message = message;
    var $id = this.id = title;


    /* ---------------creating HTML prototype */
    var $mainDiv = $("<div></div>").appendTo($("#wrapper"));
    $mainDiv.attr('id', $id);
    $mainDiv.addClass('main-div');
    var $dismissButton = $("<button>X</button>").appendTo($mainDiv);
    $dismissButton.attr('id', 'dismissButton'); 
    var $pTitle = $("<h2></h2>").appendTo($mainDiv);
    $pTitle.attr('id', 'title');
    $pTitle.text($title);
    var $para = $("<p></p>").appendTo($mainDiv);
    $para.attr('id', 'message');
    $para.text($message); 
    var $ul = $("<ul></ul>").appendTo($mainDiv);
    var $li1 = $("<li></li>").appendTo($ul);
    $li1.attr('id', 'okButton'); 
    var $button = $("<button>Ok</button>").appendTo($li1);
    $button.addClass('buttons');

    /* ---------------Dismissing notifications */ 

    $("#dismissButton").click(function() {
        document.getElementById($id).remove();
    }); 

};
```

So, the prototype is made using `new Notification(*arguments here*)` and there we get a box with a notification widget. so far so good.
when i press the X button (id `dismissbutton`) it should remove the box, and it does. 
However. if i use the `new notification` several times i get several boxes (with different ids for the `$mainDiv`) with their dismiss buttons not working. the upmost widget box's dismiss button is the only one that works, and it deleted all the other boxes as well.

I need to seperate them and have the dismiss button working for each box seperately.

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are creating multiple elements with the same ID (which is invalid HTML by the way).

Every time your run

```
var $dismissButton = $("<button>X</button>").appendTo($mainDiv);
        $dismissButton.attr('id', 'dismissButton')
```

A new "dismiss button" is being created, which has the same ID (`dismissButton`) with the previous "dismiss buttons" (if any).

The other thing is that every time you run

```
$("#dismissButton").click(function() {
          document.getElementById($id).remove();
    });
```

You instruct **only the first** "dismiss button" to remove the element identified by the ID `$id` when clicked.

In my opinion the best way to fix this is by using references to the elements themselves and not IDs.

So I would make the creation of the dismiss button like this;

```
var $dismissButton = $("<button>X</button>").appendTo($mainDiv);
```

And determine its click callback like this

```
$dismissButton.on('click', function () {
    $mainDiv.remove();
});
```

This should work fine for you.

Last, but not least I would avoid giving the same ID to any elements, since it produces invalid HTML code. You are doing so in the following lines

- `$dismissButton.attr('id', 'dismissButton');`
- `$pTitle.attr('id', 'title');`
- `$para.attr('id', 'message');`
- `$li1.attr('id', 'okButton');`

Comment: It doesn't instruct all the dismiss buttons. `$("#dismissButton")` only matches the first button with that ID. So every time he creates a new dismiss button, he adds a handler to the first one, none of the new ones.

Comment: first, i took the ids advice and removed any ids from the page. they were originaly made for the css . I will find a way to style all the buttons without any ids. needless to say, without ids this works.

Comment: You can use classes instead of IDs to style them with CSS. Actually classes are a better choice than IDs in general.